# How to send picture to email body in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a C# Winforms application I'm working on in Visual Studio 2010, the page in question is a bug reporting form - I have all the details set, email sends fine etc. My issue is attaching a screenshot to the email in the body, I have code set up to allow users to find and select a screenshot they take and attach to the form, but in the body itself it just gives me the text "System.Windows.Forms.Picturebox", or various similarities to that if I try .image.

I've had a look around via Google and here, but can only find topics that are to do with embedding the image or attaching it (and thus require to enter in a specific folder/image etc), whereas my users will be attaching their own image and name from different places. Is there anyway to get the image to be picked up without having to hardcode a location and name that my users will have to follow each time?

Code below:

```
    private void btnBugEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    try
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("details here");
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.From = new MailAddress("email here");
        string mailBox = txtBugAdd.Text.Trim();
        message.To.Add(mailBox);
        string mailFrom = txtEmailFromBug.Text.Trim();
        message.CC.Add(mailFrom);
        string mailCC = txtMailCCBug.Text.Trim();
        message.Bcc.Add(mailCC);
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.Body = "Bug Report - please see below: " +
            "\n" + "<br>" + "<b>" + "1. What were you doing at the time of the error?" + "</b>" +
                "\n" + "<br>" + rtbTimeOfError.Text +
                "\n" + "<br>" + "<b>" + "2. Are you able to repeat the steps and achieve the same error?" + "</b>" +
                "\n" + "<br>" + rtbCanRepeat.Text +
                "\n" + "<br>" + "<b>" + "3. Does this problem happen again if you change any of the details you have entered?" + "</b>" +
                "\n" + "<br>" + rtbChangeDetails.Text;
        message.Subject = "Bug Report";
        var image = pboxBugImage.Image;
        using(var ms = new MemoryStream()) 
        {
          image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);            
          message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(ms, "Screenshot.jpg"));    
          client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("credentials here");
          client.Port = System.Convert.ToInt32(25);
          client.Send(message);
        }
        new Endpage().Show();
        this.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("my comment here");
    }
}
```

Comment: Either attach the image or host the image somewhere accessible and add the appropriate URL/img-element to the body. (The former is probably more appropriate.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look to the following link

[system.net.mail.mailmessage.attachments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.attachments(v=vs.110).aspx)

You cannot put a winforms control inside the mailmessage :) it is outputted with `ToString()`... that is what you see in mail

**Example**

```
private void btnBugEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    try
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("details here");
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.From = new MailAddress("email here");
        string mailBox = txtBugAdd.Text.Trim();
        message.To.Add(mailBox);
        string mailFrom = txtEmailFromBug.Text.Trim();
        message.CC.Add(mailFrom);
        string mailCC = txtMailCCBug.Text.Trim();
        message.Bcc.Add(mailCC);
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.Body = "Bug Report - please see below: " +
            "\n" + "<br>" + "<b>" + "1. What were you doing at the time of the error?" + "</b>" +
                "\n" + "<br>" + rtbTimeOfError.Text +
                "\n" + "<br>" + "<b>" + "2. Are you able to repeat the steps and achieve the same error?" + "</b>" +
                "\n" + "<br>" + rtbCanRepeat.Text +
                "\n" + "<br>" + "<b>" + "3. Does this problem happen again if you change any of the details you have entered?" + "</b>" +
                "\n" + "<br>" + rtbChangeDetails.Text;
        message.Subject = "Bug Report";
        var image = pboxBugImage.Image;
        using(var ms = new MemoryStream()) 
        {
          image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);            
          message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(ms, "Screenshot.jpg"));    
          client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("credentials here");
          client.Port = System.Convert.ToInt32(25);
          client.Send(message);
        }
        new Endpage().Show();
        this.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("my comment here");
    }
}
```

Take a look at your resources and dispose the memorystream. I didnt for the example, because i wrote it here in editor

Comment: Code updated - by empty I mean when I check the email and click on the image attachment to view it, it reads "Windows Photo Viewer can't display this picture because the file is empty"

Comment: Please Debug the mailsending and look at `var Image`if it has a size and so on ... and look if the `MemoryStream` holds some Bytes after Image.Save()

Comment: Debug result - size reads as Height 173, Width 167, IsEmpty false. MemoryStream - This part I'm not quite sure on?

Comment: look at `ms.Length` ... it has to be greater 0

Comment: breakpoint at `message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(ms, "Screenshot.jpg")); ` or just make `Console.WriteLine(ms.Length);`somewhere inside the using block

Comment: Thanks - Length 14049, canread, seek and write true, position 14049

Comment: okay :) 1. try it without the using block to find out if its disposed before sending. 2. when you make screenshot, which imageformat do you use ? Maybe you have to Change it here `image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);`

Comment: I use .jpg format. Debug result after removing the using block - can read/write/seek true, capacity 18048, length 14049

Comment: isnt the Image empty now ?

Comment: or ... could it be that you have a spamfilter or something the empties the Image ?

Comment: Yes it is still empty, and to my knowledge we have no spamfilter emptying the image.

Comment: i think you have to Play with the `Image.Save()`method. I cant see the Problem from here :(

Comment: I shall do, thank you very much for your help and insight S.L, muchly appreciated.